# php artisan can't find existing databases even when they are clearly there

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Been trying to get into Laravel 5.1 lately. It's not going well, sometimes it won't even do the most basic things. for example:

```
Sebastians-MacBook-Pro:restaurante STianR$ php artisan migrate

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'dbname'
```

But when I access mysql directly:

```
Sebastians-MacBook-Pro:restaurante STianR$ mysql -u root -proot
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 166
Server version: 5.6.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create database dbname;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'dbname'; database exists
mysql>
```

What in the world does this even mean? I'm trying to make it run with MAMP, could it be that somehow I have two diferent sql servers and they are mixing up?

This is my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=[key - not sure if sensitive info]

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Check your `/config/database.php` file and try to change the config there.